# PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: plsql

Am getting this error **'PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist'** in Oracle 11G when I try to runt his portion of my script. It seems the select statement isn't parsing the name of the variable from the cursor. Need help to ensure this can read the table name variable from the cursor.

```
DECLARE
  ITEM_ERROR     NUMBER;
  CNT_SITE       VARCHAR2(46);

  CURSOR C_SITEID IS
     SELECT OBJECTNAME,ATTRIBUTENAME FROM MAXATTRIBUTE    WHERE ATTRIBUTENAME LIKE 'SITE%'   GROUP BY OBJECTNAME,ATTRIBUTENAME, COLUMNNAME;            
     SITEIDRec    C_SITEID%RowType;

 BEGIN
 BEGIN
 OPEN C_SITEID;
 LOOP
   FETCH C_SITEID into SITEIDRec;
   EXIT WHEN C_SITEID %NOTFOUND;
       BEGIN  
         SELECT COUNT(SITEID) into CNT_SITE FROM SITEIDRec.OBJECTNAME
          WHERE  SITEID  IN ('COLLEGE NANO SCI ENG-TGCM','FREESCALE-BALAZS','TGCM-GLOBAL FOUNDRIES','INTL RECTIFIER-TGM','TGCM-DMOS5','TGCM-IMFT','TGCM-TRIQUINT','GP-TRIQUINT');
       EXCEPTION
          WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
       END;
 END LOOP;
 --COMMIT;
 CLOSE C_SITEID;
 --COMMIT;
 EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
 END;
 --COMMIT;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    MSG_TEXT := SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,200);
  --COMMIT;
   raise;
END;
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you have `FROM TableName` **missing** in your query and hence it's rightly complaining.

```
SELECT COUNT(SITEID) into SITEIDRec.OBJECTNAME
      WHERE SITEID IN 
             ('COLLEGE NANO SCI ENG-TGCM','FREESCALE-BALAZS',
               'TGCM-GLOBAL FOUNDRIES','INTL RECTIFIER-TGM','TGCM-DMOS5',
               'TGCM-IMFT','TGCM-TRIQUINT','GP-TRIQUINT');
```

Please correct your query by adding the `From TableName`.

EDIT: Try using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` as below

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(SITEID) into CNT_SITE FROM ' 
                    || SITEIDRec.OBJECTNAME ||
         ' WHERE SITEID IN (''COLLEGE NANO SCI ENG-TGCM'',''FREESCALE-BALAZS'',
               ''TGCM-GLOBAL FOUNDRIES'',''INTL RECTIFIER-TGM'',''TGCM-DMOS5'',
               ''TGCM-IMFT'',''TGCM-TRIQUINT'',''GP-TRIQUINT'')';
```

Comment: I had it there, it seems it was a typo. After adding it I still dont seem to parse the tablename value into the select statement even after I have fetched it from my cursor.

Comment: @SwissJura: Check if the updated section in the answer is helpful. The idea is the create a SQL string and run it using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` (dynamic query)

Comment: @Ben: I though it's a string value hence suggested. Removed as it was not required anyway.

Comment: @SwissJura: I am not sure how but saw `into CNT_SITE` in the end. I just corrected the query. Can you please try with the updated query and let me know?

Comment: Hi Yogendra, Am still getting the 'table or view doest not exist' error when running this portion of my simple script here. Anyone can help me see the issue when am running in SQl Developer for oracle?

Comment: @SwissJura Can you please print the SITEIDRec.OBJECTNAME and the constructed query before doing `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` i.e. create query test in a variable and do the DBMS output. I am suspecting the value in your cursor as the cause.